# How do i write if statement on this code?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
v_id NUMBER := 200;
v_fname VARCHAR2(20);
v_lname VARCHAR2(20);
v_sal NUMBER; BEGIN
SELECT first_name, last_name, salary
INTO v_fname, v_lname, v_sal
FROM STAFF
WHERE id=v_id;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_fname||' '||v_fname||' makes '||v_sal); END; /
```

Saw this code in a StackOverflow post. Wondering how do I print on the screen a message only in case the salary of the selected record is higher than 5000 pounds?

What would be the PL/SQL for that and where do I put it in the exi?

I am learning Oracle for a week now and trying to go through the documentation as much as I can. But having a hard time understanding everything.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: An option would be adding `AND salary > 5000` to the trailing part of the current select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Simply this:

```
DECLARE
   v_id NUMBER := 200;
   v_fname VARCHAR2(20);
   v_lname VARCHAR2(20);
   v_sal NUMBER; 
BEGIN
   SELECT first_name, last_name, salary
   INTO v_fname, v_lname, v_sal
   FROM STAFF
   WHERE id=v_id;
   IF v_sal > 5000 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_fname||' '||v_fname||' makes '||v_sal); 
   END IF;

END; 
/
```